# Dataframe containing nested lists to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe which has nested lists as column values like given below:

```
    col1         col2   
0   [1, 1]      [a, b, c]   
1   [0, 0, 0]   [d, e, f]
```

When I convert the dataframe to csv , I get something like this:

```
   col1      col2   
  [1 1]  ,  [a b c] 
  [0 0 0] , [d e f]
```

Basically, the commas from the nested lists disappear and when I read back the dataframe from csv I don't get the commas.
How can I maintain the commas and save the csv to something like this:

```
   col1          col2   
  [1,1]    ,    [a, b, c]   
  [0, 0, 0] ,   [d, e, f]
```

P.S : I would like a pandas solution to creating the csv

Comment: What is `print (df.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: `{'col1': {0: '[1 1]', 1: '[0 0 0]'}, 'col2': {0: "['a' 'b' 'c']", 1: "['d' 'e' 'f']"}}` after reading from csv and `{'col1': {0: array([1, 1]), 1: array([0, 0, 0])}, 'col2': {0: array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object), 1: array(['d', 'e', 'f'], dtype=object)}}` initially

Answer (score 1):

I think there are not lists, but arrays, so if write to csv comma are removed:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[np.array([1,1]), np.array([0,0,0])]})
print (df)
        col1
0     [1, 1]
1  [0, 0, 0]

df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
print (df)
      col1
0    [1 1]
1  [0 0 0]
```

Possible solution is convert arrays to lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[np.array([1,1]), np.array([0,0,0])]})

df = df.applymap(list)
print (df)
        col1
0     [1, 1]
1  [0, 0, 0]

df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
print (df)
        col1
0     [1, 1]
1  [0, 0, 0]
```

Last for lists from string representation of lists use:

```
import ast

df = df.applymap(ast.literal_eval)
print (df)
        col1
0     [1, 1]
1  [0, 0, 0]
```